# Multi inheritance for generic

Tags: java

I want to have a method with argument `x` which can implement `Deque` or `AbstractQueue`. How to write it?

This is my try: I know it is bad, but thx to this you will understand what I want to have:

```
public <T extends Deque || T extends AbstractQueue> void solve(T x, Function<T, String> fun) {
fun.apply(x);
}
```

sometimes I want to put `ArrayDeque` as `x`:

```
solve(new ArrayDeque<String>, Deque::pollFirst);
```

and sometimes I want to put `PriorityQueue` as x:

```
solve(new PriorityQueue<String>, Queue::poll);
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken - *Queue* is an interface, and *AbstractQueue* implements that. So why is `T implements Queue` not good enough?

Comment: Because `Queue` doesn't have `pollFirst()` method which I will need

Comment: What do you intend to do in the `solve()` method? You could use a `Supplier` instead of `Function`.

Comment: You can use polymorphism and have 2 functions one with T extends Deque and the other with T extends AbstractQueue or use a generic T extends Object

Comment: In solve method I want to take first or second argument return it to variable and remove it from the Queue. If I have 2 methods whan with `T extends Deque` and other `T extends AbstractQueue` then I miss DRY rule.

Comment: Do you actually do anything with `T` that requires it to be bounded? So far it just looks like your `solve()` method is way too complicated than it needs to. How about editing the question and showing how `solve()` would look like in all its glory when it's finished.

Comment: Oh, maybe ya're write that my method does to much. This is the point. I will exagerate polling to sole method.

Comment: So far I'm not convinced that your method does anything. It looks like you're creating problems where none exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the described problem by using the type `<T extends Queue>`, since both `ArrayDeque` and `PriorityQueue` implement `java.util.Queue`. This is very similar to what GhostCat suggested in the comments.

Interface `Deque` extends `Queue`, so you can actually use `<T extends Queue>`. Method `Deque::pollFirst` is covered by the type declaration `<T extends Queue>`.

This is the implementation I would suggest:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDeque<String> x = new ArrayDeque<>();
    x.add("foo");
    solve(x, Deque::pollFirst); // first case
    PriorityQueue<String> x1 = new PriorityQueue<>();
    x1.add("bar");
    solve(x1, Queue::poll); // second case
}

public static <T extends Queue> void solve(T x, Function<T, String> fun) {
    String res = fun.apply(x);
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

This prints out:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: There's no need even for the `extends Queue` based on the (lack of) information given by OP.

Comment: @Kayaman I noticed that too. But then you can use a Stack and `Stack::pop` for example and other classes with a method which returns a String. By using `<T extends Queue>` you will not be able to use these other classes.

Comment: But so far there hasn't been a single reason why it **shouldn't** be allowed. The OP can't explain himself clearly, so it will remain a mystery what he actually needed.

Comment: @Kayaman my understanding is that there should be a limitation to method references related to queues which return a String. By using `<T extends Queue>` you are limiting to these methods. My understanding is based on the referral to `Deque::pollFirst` and `Queue::poll` in the question. I agree that the question is not well formulated and that there has been a good amount of guessing to understand this question.

Comment: Your understanding is based on the explanations of someone who doesn't have a good grasp of English. The code shows no need to limit anything. If only the OP had displayed the code in `solve()` instead of concentrating on the method signature we'd actually have some *real* information.

Comment: `Stack` extends `Vector` which is legacy and slow.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution to use the fact that `new ArrayDeque()` is equal `new PriorityQueue((a,b) -> 1)`